# What is diffrence between CLONE and copying the object?

Tags: php, oop

Does it make any difference if i copy object by simply assign it to another object instead of clone it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simple assign it, like:

```
$obj2 = $obj;
```

then you don't copy the object. You copy the *reference* to the object. Thus, `$obj2` and `$obj` point to the same object.

See also [*Objects and references*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

**Example:**

```
class A {
  public $foo = 'bar'; 
}

$obj = new A();
$obj2 = $obj;

$obj2->foo = 'foo too';

echo $obj->foo . PHP_EOL;

$obj = new A();
$obj2 = clone($obj);

$obj2->foo = 'foo too';

echo $obj->foo . PHP_EOL;
```

prints

```
foo too
bar
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/cbrRRprN)

Comment: too many keystrokes to type 'great' in full? I hope you don't name your variables like that...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Felix Kling's answer, using clone enables usage of __clone() magic method.

```
class Obj{
   public $cloned = 0;
   public function __clone(){
      $this->cloned++;
   }
}

$obj1 = new Obj();
$obj2 = $obj1;
echo 'Times cloned: ' . $obj2->cloned; // returns 'Times cloned: 0'
var_dump($obj2 === $obj1); // true

$obj3 = clone $obj1;
echo 'Times cloned: ' . $obj3->cloned; // returns 'Times cloned: 1'
var_dump($obj3 === $obj1); // false
```